# Vector space of translations of a L^1 function is not dense in L^1

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, dual-spaces

Let $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ such that the Fourier transform of $f$ equals to $0$ for a  $\xi_{0} \in \mathbb R$: $\mathcal Ff(\xi_{0}) = 0$.

Let $\tau_{s}f(x) = f(x-s)$, $s \in \mathbb R$.
I want to show that the vector space made of all the translations $\tau_{s}f$ of $f$ isn't dense in $L^1(\mathbb R)$.

That is to show that $ \exists  \epsilon > 0:$ $|| \tau_{s}f - f||_{1} > \epsilon$, when $s \to 0$.

To do this, I use the continuous linear form $\phi : L^1(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$, where $\phi(f) = \mathcal Ff(\xi_{0})$.

Therefore, I have to show that $| \phi(\tau_{s}f) - \phi(f)| > \epsilon$ when $s \to 0$.

I end up having:
 $|\phi(\tau_{s}f) - \phi(f) | = |\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)dx |$, once I made $s \to 0$.

Here, I don't know how to conclude. Obviously, I want to have $|\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)dx | >0$, and $|\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)dx | = 0$ if $f \equiv 0$, but I think there is an argument that excludes this case thanks to the Fourier transform, and I can't recall what it is.

Any help please ?

Comment: What you say you have to show is (i) absolutely not what you have to show, and also (ii) false.

Comment: Since $\phi$ is continuous, $ f_{n} \to f $ in $L^1$ $\Rightarrow \phi(f_{n}) \to \phi(f)$. Why can't I take the negation ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Look. Here's a FACT: If $f\in L^1$ then $||\tau_sf-f||_1\to0$ as $s\to0$. You say that you have to show the FACT is false. That's impossible. Luckily what you actuually have to show has nothing to do with $||\tau_s f-f||_1$.

Comment: You're confused about what you have to show. HINT: I suspect the problem is you're using the letter $f$ to refer to some element of $L^1$ that you havve to show exists with a certain property. You can't do  that - $f$ refers to the given function.

Comment: Say $V$ is the vector space spanned by the translates of $f$. Now exactly what does it mean to say that $V$ is not dense in $L^1$?

Comment: $V$ is not dense in $L^1(\mathbb R)$ if there exists $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ such that $\forall (f_{n})_{n} \in V$, I have $|| f - f_{n}||_{1} > \epsilon$, for some $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: That's exactly the error I guessed you were making! You can't use the letter $f$ there, because $f$ is already fixed. You need to say this: There exists $g\in L^1$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that $||v-g||>\epsilon$ for every $v\in V$.

Comment: Can I use the form $\phi$ then ? Starting from this, does the rest of my reasoning is right ?

Comment: Actually, It would be: $\forall g \in L^1$ such that $g \neq f$, $||g - v|| > \epsilon$.

Comment: I can't answer that until you show us exactly the argument you have in mind.

Comment: No! Actually it's _not_ what you say it actually is.

Comment: I've actually worked it out now. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fourier transforms of $\tau_sf$ also vanish at $\xi_0$.
If $(g_n)$ is a sequence of $L^1$ functions with $\mathcal{F}g_n(\xi_0)=0$
converging in $L^1$ norm to $G$, then $$|\mathcal{F}g_n(\xi_0)
-\mathcal{F}G(\xi_0)|\le\|f_n-G\|_1$$
and so $\mathcal{F} G(\xi_0)=0$. But there are $L^1$ functions
whose Fourier transforms vanish nowhere...

Comment: But it is not the case for the $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ I have to use since $\mathcal F f(\xi_{0}) = 0$, right ? What did I miss ?

Comment: What it looks to me like you're missing is the _definition_ of "$V$ is not dense in $L^1$". What is the definition of that, exactly?

Comment: I used: $V$ is not dense in $L^1(\mathbb R)$ if there exists $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ such that $\forall (f_{n})_{n} \in V$, I have $|| f - f_{n}||_{1} > \epsilon$, for some $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: @AudreyI Here $f$ is bad notation $\ddot\frown$. Let's make it $g$ instead, then any $g$ with $\mathcal{F}g(\xi_0)\ne0$ works....

Comment: It is clear now, I understand where my mistake was. Thank you !